# Python multiprocessing Queue memory management

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing

Say I have the `Main` processes and 2 additional processes `A` and `B`. In this program A is supposed to send data to B. If we have some code like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def process_a(iterable, q):

    for x in iterable:
        q.put(x)

def process_b(q):

    while some_condition():
        x = q.get()


iterable = some_iterable()
q = Queue()

pa = Process(target=process_a, args=(iterable, q))
pb = Process(target=process_b, args=(q,))

pa.start()
pb.start()

pa.join()
pb.join()
```

given that the Queue `q` was created in the Main process, does the data flow like this?

```
A => Main => B
```

If so, is there a way to have a `Queue` initialized on `B` and passed to `A` such that data goes directly from `A` to `B` skipping `Main`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> given that the Queue q was created in the Main process, does the data flow like this?

```
A => Main => B
```

No. As explained in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue), a `Queue` is just an auto-synchronizing wrapper around a `Pipe`. When you pass a `Queue` to a child, you're just passing that `Pipe` and some locks.

And the `Pipe` is just a wrapper around an operating system pipe. When you pass a `Pipe` to a child, you're just passing the pipe's file descriptor/handle.

Ignoring the locks, process A is basically just writing to a pipe, and process B is just reading from it.

The locks do make things a bit more complicated (and may also mean that process A spins up a hidden background thread), but they still don't involve the main process at all.

Unless the main process calls a method on a queue, it has nothing to do with that queue at all.